# AWS Amplify AppSync @function on a model field

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm creating an Amplify Schema for a blog that looks something like this:

```
 type Post @model {
   id: ID!
   caption: String!
   src: String!
 }
```

I want to add a new field in the **Post** model to calculate the number of times a **Post** was liked. 
It gets this data from a different API.

Is there a way to run a function on **a model field only** something like this.

```
 type Post @model {
   id: ID!
   caption: String!
   src: String!
   likes: String @function("getLikesLambda-${dev}")
 }
```

How would the `getLikesLambda` code look?
I've seen code on the official documentation on implementing resolvers but all of them tie the @function to *type query* which is not exactly what I'm looking for.

Let me know if you guys have any suggestions or if anything is unclear.

Comment: Was literally just about to type out the same question.... From my quick testing, as far as I can tell you can't do it :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your resolver can be attached to any field, not only on the Query root

I have implemented something similar

On your graphQL schema:

```
  likes: String @function(name: "getLikesLambda-${env}")
```

Add a new lambda function calling `amplify function add`

And then write your code, here is a Python example, but you can use any language supported.

```
import boto3

def handler(event, context):
  print('received event:')
  print(event)

  if 'typeName' in event and event['typeName'] == 'Post' and event['fieldName'] == 'likes':
    print("Resolve field likes")
    # Do your logic to get the likes
    likes = getLikes()
    return likes

  return ''
```

Answer (score 0):

@danielfranca is totally right. I haven't tested it yet but I recently found some documentation that I hadn't seen before here: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/directives. There is an example here for functions which has this:

```
type Query {
    posts: [Post] @function(name: "GraphQLResolverFunction")
}
type Post {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    comments: [Comment] @function(name: "GraphQLResolverFunction")
}
type Comment {
    postId: ID!
    content: String
}
```